# How to display Bluetooth Icon -- should I use a directive or a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

#### Should I use a directive or a controller?

I have a service that returns if I use bluetooth in the application or not. and I want to be able to indicate them in an on-screen icon. I seemed to read that to manipulate the DOM, either to create elements to modify or eliminate them, directives must be used. someone could give me an example of how it would be to implement a directive that does this. or would it be nice to use a controller? Thank you

**controller**

`$scope.showIcon = bluetooth.useBluetooth();`

**html**

```
 <div ng-show="showIcon">
    <img ng-src="ruta"/>
 </div>
```

**service**

```
function useBluetooth() {
        return usaBluetooth;
}
```

Comment: Show the code for the `useBluetooth` function.

Comment: do you want it to be displayed at any moment or after a route change?

Comment: @georgeawg there is

Comment: @AlekseySolovey all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `useBluetooth` function is a simple getter function is can be used by the `ng-show` directive directly:

```
$scope.useBluetooth = bluetooth.useBluetooth;
```

### Usage:

```
 <div ng-show="useBluetooth()">
    <img ng-src="ruta"/>
 </div>
```

On each digest cycle, the `ng-show` directive will fetch the bluetooth state and show or hide the element accordingly.

When using functions in [Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) it is important that they be as simple as possible because they will be called every digest cycle sometimes multiple times.

---

> but is it okay that I'm always monitoring the change of that variable? that value is defined only at the beginning and does not change throughout the application

If the expression will not change once set, it is a candidate for [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding):

```
 <div ng-show="::useBluetooth()">
    <img ng-src="ruta"/>
 </div>
```

The main purpose of one-time binding expression is to provide a way to create a binding that gets deregistered and frees up resources once the binding is stabilized. Reducing the number of expressions being watched makes the digest loop faster and allows more information to be displayed at the same time.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - One-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).

---

> but in the html do I have direct access to the service?or do I have to keep using the controller?

A [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) can be used to put the service on scope:

```
app.directive("useBluetooth", ["bluetooth", function(bluetooth) {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$bluetooth = bluetooth;
    }
}])
```

#### Usage:

```
<div use-bluetooth ng-show="::$bluetooth.useBluetooth()">
    <img ng-src="ruta"/>
 </div>
```

---

> forgive me for asking you. But is that a good practice?

My personal preference would be to use a component:

```
app.component("showBluetoothIcon", {
     controller: ['bluetooth', function(bluetooth) {
         this.bluetooth = bluetooth;
     }]),
     template: `
         <img ng-show="$ctrl.bluetooth.useBluetooth()" ng-src="ruta"/>
     `
})
```

#### Usage:

```
<show-bluetooth-icon></show-bluetooth-icon>
```

By combining the controller and the template in a single component, it becomes easy to understand, debug, test, and maintain.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Understanding Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: but is it okay that I'm always monitoring the change of that variable? that value is defined only at the beginning and does not change throughout the application

Comment: but in the html do I have direct access to the service?or do I have to keep using the controller?